# Batch file to rename file if exist

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have seen the other posts in this site like 
[Renaming a file after IF EXIST check within ++ FOR loop in a Windows batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11439790/renaming-a-file-after-if-exist-check-within-for-loop-in-a-windows-batch-file)

But since i am very new to writing batch am not able to understand those links.

I have an existing batch which works fine if the file exist. But if it does not then throws error. I want my existing batch to be modified in such a way that if the required file does not exist it will simply skip, with out throwing any error.In my case the file name is constant.

```
FOR /R "S:\SOURCES\TATW\ANALYZED\TRANSFER_AGENCY_TA_WEBSERVICES" %%f IN (WEb.config) DO REN "%%f" Web.config.xml
```

Comment: Firstly, you probably ought to `ren "%%~ff" newname` to expand `%%f` to its fully qualified drive:\path\to\filename.  To answer your question, you could just replace `REN` with `2>NUL REN` to suppress errors.  Otherwise, I think what you're looking for is `for... do if exist "%%~ff" ren "%%~ff" Web.config.xml`

Comment: A big thank you... It solved my problem....@rojo